# How to wait for DOM elements to finish rendering in Angular 2 Unit Tests

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have the following test. It focuses an html element, sets it's value and then triggers the blur event handler. The blur event triggers a validation check which, if invalid should disable a save button.

Currently during a test run this is failing, however if I set a break point and walk through it, it will properly set the disabled attribute on the save button and work.

Based on that my guess is that the whenStable promise is not waiting for the elements to finish re-rendering completely. So I threw a setTimeout to wait a whole second before checking the button state, that still isn't working for me.

Is there a function on the ComponentFixture class that will wait for the elements to completely re-render before triggering a callback or resolving a promise or whatever?

```
fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
                inputHomePhone.nativeElement.focus();
                setInputValue(inputHomePhone, "123");
                inputHomePhone.nativeElement.blur();
                fixture.detectChanges();
                return fixture.whenStable();
            })
            .then(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    expect(btnSave.classes['disabled']).toBe(true);
                    expect(btnSave.nativeElement.disabled).toBe(true);
                    debugger;
                }, 1000)
            })
```

The Html for the button here. It will be disabled when any input values on the form are invalid.

```
 <button *ngIf="!loading"
                    id="btn-save"
                    [class.disabled]="!(profileForm?.valid)"
                    class="btn primary top-space uppercase"
                    [disabled]="!(profileForm?.valid)"
                    (click)="saveChanges()">
                SAVE
            </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured out a way to trigger blur that works for me.

Doing it through the nativeElement property makes it work randomly. I am sure this is due to however Angular 2 is managing DOM events. By changing the line

`inputHomePhone.nativeElement.blur();`

To

`inputHomePhone.triggerEventHandler('blur', null);`

The save button disables immediately and the tests pass every time now.

I think in general you are supposed to use the `triggerEventHandler` function to test using DOM events in Angular 2.